# SonarQube 5.1 shows no issues when going to detail

Tags: sonarqube

I installed SonarQube 5.1 on a Linux server and ran some java project analysis. In the project dashboard, the issues (blocking, critical, major) are visible. If I click on one of the issue counts, the component_issues page is open but on the left side, all the indicators are zero.

[image: 15 issues on dashboard]

[image: but none on the issue page]

In the log there is nothing relevant.

Comment: Have you clean your data/es folder before upgrading ?

Comment: I installed it from scratch on a test server that will replace the current 3.7.1 (that is installed in production). The defect is only on some projects, some others are correctly displayed.

Comment: @Mario Do you see JavaScript errors in the JS console of your browser?

Comment: Dear @Fabrice, there are no javascript errors, either on Chrome and IE.

Comment: The only reason that could explain a difference between the figures in the widget and the ones on the Issues page is that after the analysis, you have modified the issues (like changing their severity, setting them to false-positive, ...). Did you make such actions?

Comment: I think this could also be due to problems in the indexing service.. can you try deleting /data/es folder and restart sonar server and see if it fixes the issue?

Comment: We didn't change the issues. The suggestion of @Techtwaddle worked perfectly!! Thanks!
P.S. I'm a newbye with stackoverflow. How to mark this issue as resolved so other users can quickly take advantage of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this could also be due to problems in the indexing service.. can you try deleting /data/es folder and restart sonar server and see if it fixes the issue?